# remove a bunch of rows by rownames - how do I initialize a null string in R?

Tags: r, initialization, sparse-matrix

I have this sparse-matrix I named N:

```
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   C1 C2 C3 C4
V1  .  3  5  2
V2  .  5  1  .
V3  .  .  .  .
V4  .  .  4  .
```

I'm trying to remove rows that have two or more missing values. I expect to end up with this:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4
V1  .  3  5  2
```

I wrote this piece of code:

```
    #iterate on rows and count: 
    #how many values in row ri are bigger than 0
    # if count is not bigger than limit, remove row ri
    limit = 3
    for(ri in 1:nrow(N)){
    count <- length(which(N[ri,]>0))
    if (count <limit){ 
        tmp <- paste("V",ri,sep="")
        rmv <- paste (rmv, tmp, sep= " ")       
    }
}

#now remove specific row names
N <- N[!rownames(N) %in% rmv, ]
```

The problem is - this doesn't work since in the first loop rmv is unspecified and I receive an error:

```
"object 'rmv' not found"
```

How can I initalize rmv?
If I use:

```
rmv <- ""
```

Then I get a string that starts with an empty space, for example:

```
> rmv
[1] " V2"
```

and then my final line doesn't work:

```
N <- N[!rownames(N) %in% rmv, ]
```

Also - this is the very first code I have ever written in R, so if there is anything major I'm missing in the basic concepts I'd love to read it (this has taken me 6 hours and a lot of reading in stackoverflow and different R tutorials, but I'm pretty proud of myself getting this far, this is my first question).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really using a sparse matrix for a 4-by-4 matrix? Or was that just for the example? (Your real matrix size could influence the answers you get.)

Comment: Just an example. My real sparse-matrix contains ~50,000 rows and ~100,000 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a large sparse matrix, you'll need to work with the matrix's `summary`, or `as.matrix` will make you run out of memory:

```
library(Matrix)

M <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4),
                  j = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2),
                  x = c(3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4))

M[tabulate(summary(M)$i) > 2, , drop = FALSE]
# 1 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#             
# [1,] . 3 5 2
```

---

Step-by-step to see how it works:

```
summary(M)
# 4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 6 entries 
#   i j x
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 2 2 5
# 3 4 2 4
# 4 1 3 5
# 5 2 3 1
# 6 1 4 2

tabulate(summary(M)$i)
# [1] 3 2 0 1

tabulate(summary(M)$i) > 2
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: thanks, this works! I used it also on the columns. One thing I'm wondering about given your solution: I read the data from a csv file, and then change it to a matrix. the data in the file is structured: i,j,x. So maybe I don't need the Matrix? tried to work straight on the dataframe, but that didn't work. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your sparse matrix is called `N`, this should do it:

```
N[rowSums(as.matrix(N) == 0) < 2, ]
```

---

A small example with some data from `?xtabs`:

```
d.ergo <- data.frame(Type = paste0("T", rep(1:4, 9*4)),
Subj = gl(9, 4, 36*4))
set.seed(15) # a subset of cases:
N <- xtabs(~ Type + Subj, 
           data = d.ergo[sample(36, 10), ], 
           sparse = TRUE)
N
# 4 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# T1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 .
# T2 1 . . . . . 1 . 1
# T3 . . . . 1 . . . .
# T4 1 . . . . . 1 . .
rowSums(as.matrix(N) == 0) ## How many missing
# T1 T2 T3 T4 
#  5  6  8  7 
## Let's remove any with more than 7 missing
N[rowSums(as.matrix(N) == 0) < 7, ]
# 2 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# T1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 .
# T2 1 . . . . . 1 . 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is much simpler... I just tried your solution on my original file which contains ~50,000 rows and 100,000 columns. However I received an error: 'problem too large'. I'm not suggesting that my solution would work better. Any idea what would work?

Comment: @nafrtiti, honestly, no idea. I don't usually work with sparse matrices.

Comment: Thanks again Ananda. Actually I don't think its a "sparse matrix" issue. Returning to my original question - if I only knew how to initialize a String to a null value I think my original piece of code should work since it proceeds line by line thus should be able to handle a big file

Comment: @nafrtiti, Out of curiosity, are you using the `Matrix` package? I believe if you search with your favorite search engine for `R error: 'problem too large'` you will find several posts relating to this error and that package, with some suggestions on what to follow too.